# WMI Namespace "Not Found"

Tags: c#, .net, wmi

I'm trying to run a bat file remotely (from XP to 2003) and running into a problem connecting to any WMI namespace other than cimv2. The code below hits a "Not Found" exception in the "GetMethodParameters" call. But if I replace "directory" with "cimv2", everything is gravy.

```
ConnectionOptions theConnection = new ConnectionOptions();
theConnection.Username = conDet.User;
theConnection.Password = conDet.Pwd;
theConnection.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;

ManagementScope theScope = new ManagementScope(String.Format(@"\\{0}\root\directory", conDet.Server), theConnection);
theScope.Connect();

ManagementClass processClass = new ManagementClass(theScope, new ManagementPath("Win32_Process"), new ObjectGetOptions());

enter code here
ManagementBaseObject inParams = processClass.GetMethodParameters("Create");
inParams["CommandLine"] = filename;

ManagementBaseObject outParams = processClass.InvokeMethod("Create", inParams, null);
```

I've checked the security on my machine and the server and the two namespaces have identical security settings. Any ideas what's going on?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are using a wrong namespace, the [`Win32_Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394372%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WMI class is defined in `root\cimv2`.

So you must rewrite your code to

```
ManagementScope theScope = new ManagementScope(String.Format(@"\\{0}\root\cimv2", conDet.Server), theConnection);
```

Comment: So you're saying that the only namespace I can connect to is cimv2? The rest are off limits?

Comment: No i'm not saying that, each time which you establish a WMI connection you must specify a particular namespace (scope). So you can connect to any existing namespace but using different WMI connections.